# Let's make cell.textLabel shorter

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I got an app with some tables.

In this table there are two labels - the `textLabel` with titles and the `detailTextLabel` with dates. But when title is really long, it is showed over the `detailTextLabel`.

How can I solve this problem?

P.S.
I tried to override `layoutSubviews` method in this way:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGSize size = self.bounds.size;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(4.0f, 4.0f, size.width, size.height); 
    self.textLabel.frame =  frame;
    self.textLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: have you try cell.textLabel.numberOfRows = 1;

Comment: if you mean numberOfLines - it is not work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly i create empty cell. Then add there UILabel as subView with tag. And change UILabel's frame

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Recent Dream";

    UITableViewCell *cell;// = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSLog(@"new cell");

        UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, self.view.frame.size.width -110, 48);
        textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        [textLabel setTag:1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    Dream *tempDream = [self.dreams objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    //Optionally for time zone converstions
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];

    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:tempDream.dateAdd];

    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bodyWrapper.png"]];

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = background;

    UILabel *textLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

    textLabel.text = tempDream.title;

    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = stringFromDate;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float newWidth = 30; //to try increase the value, while all will be right.
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(4.0f, 4.0f, size.width - newWidth, size.height);
```

Comment: before that i tried to replace size.width to numbers. it is not solving of problem =(